# Listening for function outcomes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm still very new to html and javascript so I have some questions on how I would do some things.  How could I track to see if a matching set of cards was picked, within my script tag?  I tried making a global variable, to track it, within my script tag however, it would cause none of the functions to fire off.  If someone could explain this for me it would be greatly appreciated.  As I stated earlier I'm just learning javascript and html(as of two days ago actually) and I'm still fuzzy on some of the logic.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>



    <h1>This is a test of the game</h1>
    <img id="topLeft" onclick="changeImageTL()" src="word-ace-card-back.jpg" width="104" height="142">
    <img src="word-ace-card-back.jpg" onclick="changeImageTM()" id="topMiddle" onclick="changeImageTM()" width="104" height="142">
    <img src="word-ace-card-back.jpg" onclick="changeImageTR()" id="topRight" width="104" height="142">
    <br>
    <img src="word-ace-card-back.jpg" onclick="changeImageML()" id="middleLeft" width="104" height="142">
    <img src="word-ace-card-back.jpg" onclick="changeImageM()" id="middle"width="104" height="142">
    <img src="word-ace-card-back.jpg" onclick="changeImageMR()" id="middleRight" width="104" height="142">
    <br>
    <img src="word-ace-card-back.jpg" onclick="changeImageBL()" id="bottomLeft" width="104" height="142">
    <img src="word-ace-card-back.jpg" onclick="changeImageBM()" id="bottomMiddle" width="104" height="142">
    <img src="word-ace-card-back.jpg" onclick="changeImageBR()" id="bottomRight" width="104" height="142">
    <br>
    <br>
    <p> Hints: </p>
    <label for="carrot" hidden = true>Carrot</label><br>
    <label for="potato" hidden = true>Potato</label><br>
    <label for="cabbage" hidden = true>Cabbage</label><br>
    <br>
    <br>
      1. <input type="text" name="question1"> are grown from the dirt and are orange<br><br><br>
      2. <input type="text" name="question2"> is a potato<br><br><br>
      3. <input type="text" name="question3"> cabbage or something<br><br><br>
      4. <input type="text" name="question3"> radish<br><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    <script>
    function changeImageTL() {

        var image = document.getElementById('topLeft');
        if ("word-ace-card-back.jpg") {
            image.src = "carrot-fb.jpg";
        } else if("carrot-fb.jpg") {
            image.src = "word-ace-card-back.jpg";
        }

    }

    function changeImageTM() {

        var image = document.getElementById('topMiddle');
        if ("word-ace-card-back.jpg") {
            image.src = "carrot-fb.jpg";
        } else if("carrot-fb.jpg") {
            image.src = "word-ace-card-back.jpg";
        }

    }

    function changeImageTR() {

        var image = document.getElementById('topRight');
        if ("word-ace-card-back.jpg") {
            image.src = "Potato_wiki.jpg";
        } else if("Potato_wiki.jpg") {
            image.src = "word-ace-card-back.jpg";
        }

    }

    function changeImageML() {

        var image = document.getElementById('middleLeft');
        if ("word-ace-card-back.jpg") {
            image.src = "corn.jpg";
        } else if("corn.jpg") {
            image.src = "word-ace-card-back.jpg";
        }

    }

    function changeImageM() {

        var image = document.getElementById('middle');
        if ("word-ace-card-back.jpg") {
            image.src = "Broccoli_wiki.jpg";
        } else if("Broccoli_wiki.jpg") {
            image.src = "word-ace-card-back.jpg";
        }

    }

    function changeImageMR() {

        var image = document.getElementById('middleRight');
        if ("word-ace-card-back.jpg") {
            image.src = "TryAgain.png";
        } else if("TryAgain.png") {
            image.src = "word-ace-card-back.jpg";
        }

    }

    function changeImageBL() {

        var image = document.getElementById('bottomLeft');
        if ("word-ace-card-back.jpg") {
            image.src = "Broccoli_wiki.jpg";
        } else if("Broccoli_wiki.jpg") {
            image.src = "word-ace-card-back.jpg";
        }

    }

    function changeImageBM() {

        var image = document.getElementById('bottomMiddle');
        if ("word-ace-card-back.jpg") {
            image.src = "Potato_wiki.jpg";
        } else if("Potato_wiki.jpg") {
            image.src = "word-ace-card-back.jpg";
        }

    }

    function changeImageBR() {

        var image = document.getElementById('bottomRight');
        if ("word-ace-card-back.jpg") {
            image.src = "corn.jpg";
        } else if("corn.jpg") {
            image.src = "word-ace-card-back.jpg";
        }

    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a 3x3 grid from what I could gather, you could create an array of size `9` where the first `3` represent the top and so on.

```
var grid = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

Where the zeros represent something not being selected.

Then place this line of code above your `changeImageTL`.

```
var grid = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
function changeImageTL() { 
...
```

Now in each function flip the bit for each click, as in:

```
// For TL...
grid[0] = !grid[0];
```

---

Now, I would recommend changing all of your methods to a single method:

```
function changeImage(pos, I1,I2) {
    var image = // Discussed later...
    // Flip the bit...
    grid[pos] = !grid[pos];
    if (image.src == I1) {
        image.src = I2;
    } else if(image.src == I2) {
        image.src = I1;
    }
}
```

Then in the *HTML* call the function as follows:

```
changeImage(0, 'word-ace-card-back.jpg', 'carrot-fb.jpg');
```

---

Then you can call another function at the end of all your new function to check:

```
function doCheck() {
    // Example...
    if(grid[0] && grid[1]) { /* Do something */ }
    // Etc....
}
```

---

Also, you do not have to use `document.getElementById` if you already know which element was clicked. Since you gave the image the `onclick`, when the element gets clicked the code called will be ran with the scope as the element. This means `image` is `this`. So, your code could look like:

```
function changeImage(pos, I1,I2) {
    // Setting it to image to add some readability.
    var image = this;
    // Flip the bit...
    grid[pos] = !grid[pos];
    if (image.src == I1) {
        image.src = I2;
    } else if(image.src == I2) {
        image.src = I1;
    }
    // Checks the grid.
    doCheck();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your functions do execute, but they need some correction:

First, the following condition is not doing what you think it does:

```
    if ("word-ace-card-back.jpg") {
```

... you need to compare that string with something.
You intended this:

```
    if (image.src == "word-ace-card-back.jpg") {
```

However, that will still not do it, because the `src` will give a full `url`, like `http://localhost/myapp/word-ace-card-back.jpg`.

You can fix this by only checking whether the image source url *contains* the particular image name, like this:

```
function changeImageTL() {
    var image = document.getElementById('topLeft');
    if (image.src.indexOf("word-ace-card-back.jpg") !== -1) {
        image.src = "carrot-fb.jpg";
    } else if(image.src.indexOf("carrot-fb.jpg") !== -1) {
        image.src = "word-ace-card-back.jpg";
    }
}
```

When `indexOf` returns `-1`, it means the argument does not occur in the string you search in (in this case `image.src`).

Now notice also that the `else` condition is really not necessary. You want to flip the image anyway, so if it is not in one direction, it *should always* be in the other. So the condition in the `else` part can be omitted:

```
function changeImageTL() {
    var image = document.getElementById('topLeft');
    if (image.src.indexOf("word-ace-card-back.jpg") !== -1) {
        image.src = "carrot-fb.jpg";
    } else {
        image.src = "word-ace-card-back.jpg";
    }
}
```

Do this correction in all functions and it should work better.

Answer (score -1):

Juste move your "script" tag and its content at the begining of the "body" (before calling the functions), and it should work as expected.

Comment: So move the entire script tag and it's contents or just the top script tag?

Comment: From the opening SCRIPT tag to the closing SCRIPT tag, both included, with everything between.